# Uploading the contents of a directory in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, file-upload

I'm developing a JSP application, and I want to be able to upload the contents of a directory to the server. So the user will select the directory he wants to upload, and somehow all its contents will be uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's time for a Framework! [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/index.html) can handle this type of jobs well and is easy to start with. Here you can take a look at a [File Upload](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-file-Upload-example-1.html) sample.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done with regular HTML/Javascript, you have to use either Java or Flash.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for this in HTML (only uploading of a single file) so there is nothing you can do in your JSP. If you want to do this in java you will have to have something client side, like a signed Applet or a jar that the user downloads and runs.

Answer (score 0):

As said, there is no way to do this in JavaScript/HTML.

If you do not want to use a Java Applet (they are clunky and your users may not have Java installed), you can let people upload a zip file and extract it on the server (there is support for this in the Java standard API). Both Windows and Mac OS allow the clients to zip a folder by right-clicking.